# Objective C: combine two elements of a vector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, text, nsarray

I have this code:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[appDelegate.client objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
```

but I want write in the cell table view also the "objectAtIndex:1" then after

```
...objectAtIndex:0...????
```

what can I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *a = [[appDelegate.client objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *b = [[appDelegate.client objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", a, b];
```

See [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [Formatting String Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).